# split output into multiple files after reaching a certain size with correct file-extension

Tags: files, filenames, split

I use

```
make | tee >(split -d -b 10000000 - debug.log.0)
```

to split the output into several debug files after reaching 10MB.

this results in files called  debug.log.000, debug.log.001, debug.log.002 ...

I could rename them afterwards with

```
for i in debug*; do echo $i; done
```

But how can I reconstruct the command, so they get the ending `.log` at the end of each file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the file-ending for the split files with the option `--additional-suffix`

```
make | tee >(split --additional-suffix=.log -d -b 10000000 - debug.0)
```

Comment: This is not posix

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +10M -exec du -shk {} \;| sed "s/\.\///g"|awk '$1 > 50 {print "split -l Specifylinenumber"  " " $2}'|sh


After above file whose size is greater than 10M will be splitted as xaa,xab,xac and so on

Use below command to get it renamed

f=1;for i in xa*; do  mv $i debug.log.00$f; f=$(($f+1)); done
```